# Nested footer selectors are not cascading the selectors in the upper nest

Tags: css, sass

I got this nested stylesheet using SASS, but the problem here is that the nested ul and li:s inside the footer counts as the same that's nested outside of it. I thought the whole point of nesting it like this was to make stuff like this easier? Or am I just doing it wrong? If so, how do I change this so that the nested ul and li inside the footer doesn't inherit properties from the ones outside of it?

```
#inbox {
    width: $maxPercentage;
    height: $maxPercentage - 10;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    margin: $center;
    position: relative;

    ul:first-child {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 0 0 15px;
        list-style: none;

        li:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #f2f2f2;
        }

        li {
            @include vertAlign(30px);
        }
    }

    footer {
        width: $maxPercentage;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: $maxPercentage;

        ul {
            margin: 0 30px 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 25px;
            float: right;

            li:first-child {
                width: auto;    
            }

            li {
                width: 30px;
                border: 0;
                display: inline-block;
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know, but it's not cascading..? The stuff in the footer doesn't overwrite what's over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably confusing yourself. Lets look at what each of those selectors renders out to:

```
#inbox ul
#inbox li
#inbox .footer ul
#inbox .footer ul li
```

SASS doesn't keep CSS from cascading. You're only increasing the specificity of your selector, not creating unique selectors inside of `.footer`.

So `#inbox .footer ul li` will have all the properties of `#inbox li` as well as `#inbox .footer ul li`. This is not different from your vanilla cascading style sheets. You can either override styles upstream, or with a more specific selector.

Nesting is most useful to describe contexts or modifiers:

```
.message{ 
    color: black;
    .success{
        color: green;
    }
    .urgent{ 
        color: red;
        .super-bad{ 
            border-image: url("skulls.gif");
        }
    }
}
```